# Can a person whom you follow but who does not follow you reply back when your tweets are protected?

Tags: tweet

Can a person whom you follow but who does not follow you reply back (not only seen) when your tweets are protected?

Suppose my tweets are protected and there is another tweeter user whom I follow but who does not follow me and whose tweets are not protected. So then if I tweet to that person by using the twitter handle @userwhodoesnotfollowme, can that person reply back to the tweet I sent?

Comment: Your question is not very clear.

Answer (score 1):

No. Protected Tweets may only be visible to your approved Twitter followers.

Comment: But when your tweets are protected and when you send a tweet to person  you follow But does not follow you, twitter displays a message that says the message was sent to the person

Comment: Tweeting and sending a tweet to someone, both are different things. If someone is following you or not you send them DM.

Comment: If someone is following you or not you send them DM. I don't understand this sentence But according to the twitter help if both parties are following each other they can send Direct Messages to each other

Comment: tweeting and sending a tweet to someone, both are different things. Well I don't think so. tweet or send a tweet both are used for the same thing which is sending a message on twitter.